# ColorPicker UWP COM Exception in Converter

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I have defined a custom `Color` class in Windows Universal Application. I want to bind a property of this type in my `ViewModel` (`ViewModel.ModelColor`) to a ColorPicker using a `ValueConverter`. Unfortunately, it doesn't work. This is what I have:

**XAML**

```
<ColorPicker Color="{Binding ModelColor, Converter={StaticResource ColorConverter}, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

**Converter**

```
 public class ColorConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
        {
            if (value == null)
            {
                return default(Color);
            }

            var c = (Color) value;
            return  Windows.UI.Color.FromArgb(c.A, c.R, c.G, c.B);
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
        {
            var c = (Windows.UI.Color) value;
            return new Color(c.A, c.R, c.G, c.B);
        }
    }
```

When I run it, it throws in the line that says:

```
 var c = (Windows.UI.Color) value;
```

This is the exception:

[image]

What's happening? I'm supposed to receive a `Windows.UI.Color` in `value`!

**EDIT:** I have inspected "value.GetType()" and this is what I'm getting. Too strange!

[image]

Comment: I deleted my wrong answer.  Very strange.  What happens if you don’t use a converter at all?

Comment: I’m curious because I plan to add this new control in my UWP project.

Comment: OK, I've created a new solution from scratch with the minimum code to produce the issue. Yes, it seems it's a bug in the control. I've already posted here: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/windows-uwp/issues/247 Please, vote it to get attention. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I got this to work:

```
public Color SelectedColor
{
    get { return ColorFromText(SelectedColorAsText); }
    set
    {
        String  newColorAsText;

        newColorAsText = TextFromColor(value);

        if (newColorAsText != SelectedColorAsText)
        {
            SelectedColorAsText = newColorAsText;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedColor));
        }
    }
}

public String SelectedColorAsText { get; set; }

private Color ColorFromText(String text)
{
    Byte    a, r, g, b;

    a = Byte.Parse(text.Substring(1, 2),    System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);
    r = Byte.Parse(text.Substring(3, 2),    System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);
    g = Byte.Parse(text.Substring(5, 2),    System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);
    b = Byte.Parse(text.Substring(7, 2),    System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);

    return Color.FromArgb(a, r, g, b);
}

private String TextFromColor(Color color)
{
    return color.ToString();
}
```

(I chose to arbitrarily have my internal representation be `"#AARRGGBB"`.)

Then, in XAML, bind the `ColorPicker`'s `Color` property using `{x:Bind}`:

```
Color="{x:Bind Path=SelectedColor, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

If you use `{Binding}`, you will receive a wonderful `Exception` regarding a `System.__ComObject` not being convertible to a `Windows.UI.Color`.